# How to hook payment created on commerce 2

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

I use commerce to create a bakery. Unfortunately, there is no module to pay by check or cash. So I use the payment example "manual".
I need to debit the user account when a payment is entered (a "balance" field has been created on the user account).
Is there a hook when a payment is created so that I can do this operation on the user entity?

Comment: There is no module for paying by check or cash because those use cases are fully covered by the Manual gateway, it's not an "example"  gateway, that's what it was built for.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use hook_entity_create() but I would rather react on Order transition event, such as `commerce_order.place.post_transition` which is triggered when Order reaches Completed state.

Comment: I just see that there is 3 state of payment.
orders/127/payments/20/operation/receive
orders/127/payments/20/operation/refund
orders/127/payments/20/operation/void

So I need to interact with these 3 payment states regardless of the bill status.
Do U think  `commerce_order.place.post_transition` should be the solution ?

Comment: Finally I must be informed when:
- there is payment completed
- A payment is avoided
For these two cases I chose the hook_entity.
- an order is completed
- a command is deleted
For the completed order I used the event :
commerce_order.place.post_transition
But I do not find a way to be informed when an order is deleted, the event commerce_order.commerce_order.delete does not work?